# tqdm in console creates newline each progress

Tags: python, tqdm

I see that for notebook environmets people should `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm` to solve such problems

```
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13147/259217 [1:15:33<23:34:11,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.756, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.05, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.594, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=3.53, per
plexity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=0.5, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.21, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=1.26, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279b8
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13148/259217 [1:15:33<23:34:14,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.756, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.05, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.594, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=3.53, per
plexity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=0.5, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.21, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=1.26, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279b8
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13148/259217 [1:15:33<23:34:14,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.75, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.15, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.589, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=3.8, perpl
exity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=1, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.189, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=1.34, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279b8]  
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13149/259217 [1:15:34<23:34:16,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.75, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.15, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.589, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=3.8, perpl
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13149/259217 [1:15:34<23:34:16,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.719, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.28, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.585, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=4.2, perp
lexity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=0.625, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.153, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=1.44, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13150/259217 [1:15:34<23:34:19,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.719, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.28, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.585, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=4.2, perp
lexity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=0.625, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.153, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=1.44, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13150/259217 [1:15:34<23:34:19,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.622, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.77, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.618, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=7.53, per
plexity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=0.5, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.249, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=2.02, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279b
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13151/259217 [1:15:35<23:34:30,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.622, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.77, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.618, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=7.53, per
plexity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=0.5, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.249, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=2.02, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279b
Epoch 1:   5%|▌         | 13151/259217 [1:15:35<23:34:30,  2.90it/s, lm_acc_train=0.807, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=0.696, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.591, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=2.3, perplexity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=0.625, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.138, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=0.834, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f2
```

Unfortunately, I'm printing it to the `stdout` and not `jupyter`.
This is my `tqdm` configuration:

```
bar = tqdm(
            desc='Training',
            initial=self.train_batch_idx,
            position=(2 * self.process_position),
            disable=self.is_disabled,
            leave=False,
            dynamic_ncols=True,
            file=sys.stdout,
            smoothing=0,
        )
```

For example, an acceptable solution for me is to see only the first `X` chars (which will change constantly, as metrics are created and vanish during training).

Answer (score 1):

(Edited)

Instead of creating a bar and updating it, you may better create a tqdm iterator on your training data, it might help, though I'm unsure. If you are already manually training, just remove all print statements throughout the training. You can still use the prints at end of each epoch/step/loop.

Or you may want to try other options: like say the alive_progress one [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-to-use-progress-bars-in-python-2dc436de81e5):

```
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import time
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
with alive_bar(len(mylist)) as bar:
     for i in mylist:
         bar()
         time.sleep(1)
         with alive_bar(9) as bar2:
             for j in range(9):
                 bar2()
                 print(j)
```

This one works great and you may use in place of tqdm.

```
for i in range(3):
    bar = tqdm(range(30), desc='Training', initial=0,  file=sys.stdout, leave=False, dynamic_ncols=True, smoothing=0, total=30, disable=False, position=i)
    #bar.write("")
    for j in bar:
        sleep(0.1)
        bar.set_postfix({"j" : j, "lm_acc_train":0.719, "lm_acc_val":0.725, "lm_loss_train":1.28, "lm_loss_val":1.31, "loss":1.585, "lr":2e-5, "perplexity_train":4.2, "perplexity_val":444, "tdm_acc_train":0.625, "tdm_acc_val":0.615, "tdm_loss_train":0.153, "tdm_loss_val":0.818, "total_loss":0, "total_loss_train":1.44, "total_loss_val":2.13, "v_num":"30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279"})
        #bar.set_postfix_str("lm_acc_train=0.719, lm_acc_val=0.725, lm_loss_train=1.28, lm_loss_val=1.31, loss=1.585, lr=2e-5, perplexity_train=4.2, perplexity_val=444, tdm_acc_train=0.625, tdm_acc_val=0.615, tdm_loss_train=0.153, tdm_loss_val=0.818, total_loss=0, total_loss_train=1.44, total_loss_val=2.13, v_num=30077a44426044bfaa332c94b4f279")
```

After the comment I tried these. However big I make the dictionary (or the string -- comment), whether I use leave = False or True, whether I import `tqdm.auto.tqdm` or `tqdm.tqdm` as tqdm, whether or not I use position=2*i, it always prints in same line in terminal for one iteration of `i`.

May I know your code, how you are printing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at alive pb, but regarding your first comment, I'm unfortunately do not print anything during training, everything you see is data attached to the tqdm module. I suspect the problem is that I add too much data to the pb thus it overflows the line in the console. When I extend the line to its maximum (2 screens) it stops generating new lines

Comment: Where exactly are you printing?? Terminal?? Command Prompt?? Any gui or something...zenit??

Comment: tmux terminal. It happens to me in any terminal(from vs code). Just to be clear, this isn't the default behavior? I.e tmux shouldn't create new line each update even if the message is longer than a full line?